# How do I split up a CSV file up into several files and keep the header row in each?

Tags: file, csv

I have tried several of the front end facing solutions and none work also have tried 6 different github tests and did not work either. The file is really big over 100K rows and over 74mb.

Comment: You can do this with code if you want to. Read the file and store the 1st row i.e header and write several files using the same header and different rows.

Comment: An `awk` one-liner should do it.